# Docker: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: ssl, docker, handshake, docker-registry

I've created my own private registry (private-registry) but I'm unable to push images to it.
Than I get the following error:

```
The push refers to a repository [private-registry:5000/ubuntu] (len: 1)
unable to ping registry endpoint https://private-registry:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://private-registry:5000/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://private-registry:5000/v1/_ping: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

The logs of the running registry are showing the following:

```
time="2015-12-14T07:59:21Z" level=warning msg="No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable." go.version=go1.5.2 instance.id=a77e1955-3688-4fe3-a06e-0341787f8d0f version=v2.2.1 
time="2015-12-14T07:59:21Z" level=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.5.2 instance.id=a77e1955-3688-4fe3-a06e-0341787f8d0f version=v2.2.1 
time="2015-12-14T07:59:21Z" level=info msg="using inmemory blob descriptor cache" go.version=go1.5.2 instance.id=a77e1955-3688-4fe3-a06e-0341787f8d0f version=v2.2.1 
time="2015-12-14T07:59:21Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:5000, tls" go.version=go1.5.2 instance.id=a77e1955-3688-4fe3-a06e-0341787f8d0f version=v2.2.1 
time="2015-12-14T07:59:21Z" level=info msg="Starting upload purge in 47m0s" go.version=go1.5.2 instance.id=a77e1955-3688-4fe3-a06e-0341787f8d0f version=v2.2.1
```

I'm unable to curl my registry (timeout).
This are the steps I performed:

First I've created selfsigned certificates:

```
mkdir -p certs && openssl req \
  -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key \
  -x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt
```

I've created my registry, which will use this certificates:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name private-registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

I gave the right permissions:

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t ~certs/
```

I've created: `/etc/docker/etc.d/private-registry:5000/`
And I copied my `domain.crt` in it.
I've edited my `/etc/hosts` and added:
`10.0.0.X private-registry` (my internal ip and the name of my registry)

I also restarted docker and my registry.

***EDIT:***

```
[centos@ ~]$ curl -v private-registry:5000
* About to connect() to private-registry port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 10.0.0.xx...
* Connected to private-registry (10.0.0.xx) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: private-registry:5000
> Accept: */*
> 

* Connection #0 to host private-registry left intact
[centos@~]$ curl -v https://private-registry:5000
* About to connect() to private-registry port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 10.0.0.xx...
* Connected to private-registry (10.0.0.xx) port 5000 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
      CApath: none
    * NSS error -5990 (PR_IO_TIMEOUT_ERROR)
* I/O operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) I/O operation timed out
```

Comment: update above about curling

Comment: Could be just exceeded amount of requests a pulling image consists of a lot of containers. Just try rerunning in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to place the certificate into this directory.

```
    /etc/docker/certs.d/private-registry.com:5000/ca.crt
```