# Gitlab-ci and docker compose: tls handshake timeout

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've got some problems trying to set up CI using Gitlab and docker: the docker-compose build fails with error

`Building web
Step 1/8 : FROM python:2.7-alpine
Service 'web' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Here is my gitlab-runner/config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "Backend-django runner"
  url = "http://gitlab.codewithme.today/ci"
  token = "4976e4153178a33029e041a0f5fe07"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:2.7-alpine"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

My own gitlab container registry works fine with letsencrypt-created certificates and the same procedure completes successfully locally on the same server with gitlab runner.

How can that problem be overcame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262275/docker-tls-handshake-timeout#34698933

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: TLS handshake timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262275/docker-tls-handshake-timeout)

Comment: @gtonic unfortunately, seems not to be the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the parameter `mtu=1300` on the network interface solved the problem.

Comment: can you elaborate what network interface you are referencing and how you set the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/work_with_agent.html

Overriding the MTU of the created network
For some environments, like VMs in OpenStack, a custom MTU is necessary. The Docker daemon does not respect the MTU in docker.json (see moby issue), so you can set the network_mtu in your config.toml to any valid value. This instructs the Docker daemon to use the correct MTU for the newly-created network.

```
[runners.docker]
  network_mtu = 1402
```